# How to include a token in a view?

Tags: tokens, drupal-views

The CiviCRM Views integration (Drupal) provides a way to create a View using data from Civi fields.  Is there a way to include the output from a Civi token in the View?

The use case is that I have a token for a custom greeting that I want to include in a View.

[For this particular situation, using the email_greeting field would be enough but it does not show in the list of fields available to add to a View.]

Comment: Could you please edit your question to explain your use-case? What is your end goal?

Comment: @Coleman - edited, hopefully that's clearer

Comment: It sounds like the real question might be "how do I add a currently unsupported field to Views"

Comment: @Coleman - I have created a separate question for that (http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/3120/225), and when tokens are just an existing field, it becomes just a different way of achieving the same thing.  However, when tokens have more logic in them than just a simple field the question is still how to include them in a View.

Comment: CiviCRM tokens generally do not contain any logic, fyi.

Comment: @Coleman - Generally, yes. But they can as this really useful post explains - https://civicrm.org/blogs/colemanw/create-your-own-tokens-fun-and-profit  :-)

Comment: Ah, classic. But if you're writing your own custom tokens you might as well write your own views fields using the views_php module.

Answer (score 1):

I am using [civicrm_entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity) which can pretty much expose everythign in civicrm to drupal views (and more) [image: filter of type greeting]

Answer (score 0):

You could write a Drupal module to call `hook_views_post_execute()` or `hook_views_pre_render()`, looping through the result set and calling your token's function for each record. However, if your email greeting formula is simple, I would call `hook_views_query_alter()` to add it into your list of select fields, concatenating the name within your SQL.